# Exception when use @Query () to return list of Employee

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

i am using spring boot want to return all list of my Employee class using @Query() annotation but it returns exception here is my code
//here is my repository clas

```java
package com.employee.Dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.employee.Entities.Employee;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee,Long> {
    
    @Query("select e FROM Employee e")
    public <List>Employee getAllEmployee();
    
    @Query(value = "  From Employee e where e.fullName=:name")
    public <List>Employee getEmployeeByName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

Here is my controller class

```java
@GetMapping("/main")
public String main(@ModelAttribute Employee employee, ModelMap model, HttpSession session) {
    List<Employee> allEmployeeQuery = this.empservice.getAllEmployeeQuery();
        allEmployeeQuery.forEach(a->System.out.println(a));
    return "main";
}
```

I want to get list of allEmploy using @Query() annotation but it throws an exception. Here are the details of the exception

```
[2m[nio-8080-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.employee.Entities.Employee cannot be cast to class java.util.List (com.employee.Entities.Employee is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.employee.Entities.Employee cannot be cast to class java.util.List (com.employee.Entities.Employee is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at com.employee.service.EmpService.getAllEmployeeQuery(EmpService.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.employee.MainController.main(MainController.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
```

I am using Spring Boot and Hibernate.

Comment: You need to use `List<Employee>` instead of `<List>Employee` in `UserRepository`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mention which field OR fields you need as result. It looks like you only have `ClassCastException` with second query because you didn't mention which details you need in result but set `<List>Employee` return type in query.

Update your query with this and try. It might solve your `ClassCastException`

```
@Query(value = "SELECT e FROM Employee e WHERE e.fullName = :name")
public List<Employee> getEmployeeByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Mark Rotteveel said in a comment about `List<Employee>` instead of `<List>Employee`, keep in mind that because you are using the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency in your project so you don't even need to use @Query for simple queries like these.

You could just define the following single line of code in your UserRepository and Spring Data JPA will create the query auto-magically:

```
List<Employee> findAllByName(String name);
```

As long as you have implemented CrudRepository or JpaRepository in your UserRepository you get a whole bunch of basic CRUD operational queries for free. So outside of your repository you can just do:

```
List<Employee> employees = userRepository.findAll();
```

Also, it's nit-picky but UserRepository should definitely be renamed to EmployeeRepository.