# Exception when use @Query () to return list of User

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I got a similar issue as [Exception when use @Query () to return list of Employee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77422110/exception-when-use-query-to-return-list-of-employee)

This is my implementation:

```java
package com.user.Dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.user.Entities.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User,Long> {
    

    @Query("""
            SELECT new com.user.UserProfileProjection(emails)
            FROM User
            WHERE id = :id""")
    Optional<UserProfileProjection> findProfileById(Long id);
}


public record UserProfileProjection(List<RestUserEmail> emails) {
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public UserProfileProjection(Object emails) {
        this(((List<UserEmail>) emails).stream().map(e -> new RestUserEmail(e.email(), e.language())).toList());
    }

    public record RestUserEmail(String email, Language language)
}
```

```
import io.hypersistence.utils.hibernate.type.json.JsonBinaryType;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

public class User extends AbstractAggregateRoot<User> {
    ...
    @Type(JsonBinaryType.class)
    private List<UserEmail> email;


    public record UserEmail(String email, Language language) {

    }
}
```

Before these implementation worked but when I replace JSON field's library from **io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62** to native hibernate it no longer works but only on deployed server(k8s which run with linux platform), my local environment (macos) still works :(

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcTypeCode;
import org.hibernate.type.SqlTypes;

public class User extends AbstractAggregateRoot<User> {
    ...
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private List<UserEmail> email;


    public record UserEmail(String email, Language language) {

    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.user.Dao.UserData$UserEmail cannot be cast to class java.util.List (package com.user.Dao.User$UserEmail is in unnamed module of loader **org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.LaunchedClassLoader** @f6f2d33; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I am using Spring Boot and Hibernate and Java 21.